# Set fragments' positions in android activities

Tags: android, position, fragment

I have a fragment that should be shown in an activity under another fragment

In the xml of the fragment I tried to use:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/second_fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/first_fragment">  
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

(please note android:layout_below="@id/first_fragment" in the layout tag)

I have also tried this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp">     
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/first_fragment"/>     
</RelativeLayout>
```

(please note android:layout_below="@id/first_fragment" in the TextView tag)

in both cases the application compile and run but the second fragment is shown on the top of the screen instead of after the first one.

Please consider that I'm adding the fragments programmatically by using FragmentTransaction and I add the second fragment after having added the first one, but in the same transaction

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Thank-you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a FrameLayout (viewGroup) in your activity xml  to hold your fragment, then add your fragment object using [add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) or [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutId, yourFragmentObject);
```

So you can align as you wish

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it doing this. In the layout I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
    </FrameLayout>  
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/top"> 
    </FrameLayout>      
</RelativeLayout>
```

then in the activity:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fr1= new Fragment1();
ft.add(R.id.top, fr1 , "top");
fr2 = new Fragment2();
ft.add(R.id.bottom, fr2, "bottom");     
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be help,

```
<fragment class="com.example.android.hcgallery.TitlesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/frag_title"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment class="com.example.android.hcgallery.ContentFragment"
        android:id="@+id/frag_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: mmm I don't have <fragment> tags in the xml of the activity. I have two xml and two Fragment classes (one for each fragment). I add the two fragments by using FragmentTransaction. In the onCreateView of the two fragment classes I inflate the correspondent xml to create and return the fragment's view

Comment: u have to use android SDK 3.0 or above.

Comment: I mean that my activity view is inflated by using an xml that does not contain any fragments. I add fragments later.I'm using the compatibility support lib